# SVG Doesn't show up in button element

Tags: html, css, svg, jsx

I'm using inline SVG ( as JSX ) on my website, I'm trying to display a hamburger menu button but it isn't showing up. Here is my code:

```
import Link from "next/link"

function Nav() {
    return (
        <nav>
            <button > /// SVG is here
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-172 -12 210 50" stroke="#000000">
                    <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth={2} d="M4 6h16M4 12h16m-7 6h7" />
                </svg>
            </button>
            <ul className="">
                <li>
                        <Link href="/">
                                <a>Main</a>
                        </Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                        <Link href="/resume">
                                <a>Resume</a>
                        </Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                        <Link href="/projects">
                                <a>Projects</a>
                        </Link>
                </li>

                <li>
                        <Link href="/blog">
                                <a>Blog</a>
                        </Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                        <Link href="/contact">
                                <a>Get in touch</a>
                        </Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );
}

export default Nav;
```

The Icon is only visible when it's outside the button tag, how do I view it while preserving the viewBox attribute?

Comment: Hard to tell with the given code only, but I would make a guess here. Sometimes `svg` needs to have `display: block` styles and specified `width` and `height` to be shown correctly. Check your browser inspection panel, give them above values, and see if it works. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you need to adjust the `viewBox` for your svg element, that way when you set your svg's `height` and `width`, your svg scales properly and you get the desired result. Here's your code which I tweaked:

```
<button> 
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="2 1 20 20" stroke="#000000" height="50px" width="50px">
       <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth={2} d="M4 6h16M4 12h16m-7 6h7" />
     </svg>
</button>
```

See it work on codepen [here](https://codepen.io/ifycode/pen/LYbPbpv).

You can learn about how `viewBox` works at [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox).